# Relation between dimensions of two subspaces of $\ell^2.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Fix some some double sequence $(y_{n,m})_{n,m\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{C}$ with $\sum_{n,m}|y_{n,m}|^2<\infty.$ Let
$$A = \{x\in\ell^2: \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{n,1}x_n = 0 \,\,\wedge\,\, \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{n,m+1}x_n = -x_m\,\,\forall m\geq 1 \},$$
$$B = \{x\in\ell^2: \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{m,n}x_n = -x_{m+1}\,\,\forall m\geq 1\}.$$
I want to show that $\text{dim } A = \text{dim } B - 1.$ I plan to do it in two steps:

1. Show that $A'= \{x\in\ell^2: \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{n,m+1}x_n = -x_m\,\,\forall m\geq 1\}$ has the same dimension as $B$ via some clever isomorphism.
2. Show that intersecting $A'$ with $\{x\in\ell^2: \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{n,1}x_n = 0\}$ reduces the dimension by $1.$

I am stuck on both steps. I think I'm missing some insight on what $A'$ and $B$ look like and how they depend on the choice of $y.$ I think it might be better to replace $y$ in the definitions of $A$, $A'$ and $B$ by the complex conjugate $\bar{y},$ to use tools from Hilbert spaces, since we can then write these sets as orthogonal complements, but even then I am still stuck. Any help with either step would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If $y_{n,m}=0$ for all $n,m$ then $A =\ell^{2}$ and $B$ is one dimensional.

Comment: Hi Kavi, could you kindly consider answering my most recent question, on Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I see that I made a typo: the $y(m)$ should have been $x_m$ in the definition of $A$. You are right. Is it true now?